# md-select pops up twice on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, material-design, angular-material

I am using md-select from the Angular-Material library, and no matter what I change, the select box comes up, closes, and then comes up again.

```
   <md-select placeholder="Set Timeframe" ng-model="specialDates">
        <md-option ng-value="{number:1, frame:'days'}" md-no-ink>Last day</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="{number:3, frame:'days'}" md-no-ink>Last 3 days</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="{number:1, frame:'weeks'}" md-no-ink>Last week</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="{number:2, frame:'weeks'}" md-no-ink>Last 2 weeks</md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Comment: Which angular material version are you using? Couldn't reproduce you problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJprjG (works fine on chrome 43.0.2357.130)

Comment: 0.9.8 - I read somewhere to include jquery before angularjs to prevent propagation. But it's already like that.

Comment: Hm, could you create a plunker/fiddle/codeopen where the problem occure?

Comment: @Numyx ugh - I can't reproduce it. Trying...

Comment: BTW turned out to be an issue with Angular version. Once I switched to 1.3.15 it worked fine.